# Set Image Source with generated RenderTargetBitmap from background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am applying a blur in a background thread to increase performance. This function is returning a `RenderTargetBitmap`. When this is done I'm invoking through the Dispatcher an update on the image and add it as content to the page. This is done like the following:

```
            System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
            Thread screenshotThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                RenderTargetBitmap img = CaptureScreen(0, 0, actualWidth, actualHeight);
                //System.Windows.Controls.Image image = imgBlur;
                //image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    image.Source = img;
                    image.Width = actualWidth;
                    image.Height = actualHeight;
                    PageContainer.Children.Add(image);
                });
            }));
            screenshotThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            screenshotThread.Start();
```

I'm adding the image to the PageContainer, this is a Grid. After running this piece of code, the image has been added to the page. However, the imagesource is null.. No image is currently visible. How can I make this image appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created the `Imagecontrol` and the `RenderTargetBitmap` on different thread. I am surprised you did not get an exception. Try adding `img.Freeze();` before setting it to the `Image.Source`.

Comment: Aaaahh, thanks! Should have seen it! I placed the `img.Freeze()` before the dispatcher invoke and it works! Thanks!